# Ecom tracking not showing up in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, analytics, google-tag-manager

I integrated Google Analytics through GTM and now I´m trying to enable e-commerce tracking. However, for some reason is not working.

*sorry due to Company privacy I changed the URL

Here is the debug code

```
Initializing Google Analytics.
analytics_debug.js:24 Loading resource for plugin: ecommerce
analytics_debug.js:24 Loading script: "https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ecommerce.js"
analytics_debug.js:24 Running command: ga("create", "UA-100134152-1", {name: "gtm1", cookieDomain: "auto"})
analytics_debug.js:24 Creating new tracker: gtm1
analytics_debug.js:24 Auto cookieDomain found: "bu.com"
analytics_debug.js:24 Running command: ga("gtm1.set", "&gtm", "2wg3b2TCH6J4M")
analytics_debug.js:24 Running command: ga("gtm1.set", "hitCallback", [function])
analytics_debug.js:24 Running command: ga("gtm1.require", "ecommerce", "//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ecommerce.js")
analytics_debug.js:24 Waiting on require of "ecommerce" to be fulfilled.
analytics_debug.js:24 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "render", Function)
analytics_debug.js:24 Running command: ga("gtm1.require", "ecommerce", "//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ecommerce.js")
analytics_debug.js:24 Waiting on require of "ecommerce" to be fulfilled.
analytics_debug.js:24 Executing Google Analytics commands.
analytics_debug.js:24 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "ecommerce", Function)
analytics_debug.js:24 Running command: ga("gtm1.require", "ecommerce", "//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ecommerce.js")
analytics_debug.js:24 Plugin "ecommerce" intialized on tracker "gtm1".
analytics_debug.js:24 Running command: ga("gtm1.ecommerce:addTransaction", {id: undefined, affiliation: undefined, revenue: undefined, shipping: undefined, tax: undefined})
analytics_debug.js:24 Running command: ga("gtm1.ecommerce:send")
analytics_debug.js:24 Running command: ga("create", "UA-100134152-1", {name: "gtm2", cookieDomain: "auto"})
analytics_debug.js:24 Running command: ga("gtm2.set", "&gtm", "2wg3b2TCH6J4M")
analytics_debug.js:24 Running command: ga("gtm2.set", "hitCallback", [function])
analytics_debug.js:24 Running command: ga("gtm2.send", "pageview")
analytics_debug.js:24 

analytics_debug.js:24 <unknown>        (&gtm)  2wg3b2TCH6J4M
analytics_debug.js:24 _j1              (&jid)  
analytics_debug.js:24 _j2              (&gjid) 
analytics_debug.js:24 adSenseId        (&a)    1515998799
analytics_debug.js:24 apiVersion       (&v)    1
analytics_debug.js:24 clientId         (&cid)  1152172694.1552546478
analytics_debug.js:24 encoding         (&de)   UTF-8
analytics_debug.js:24 hitType          (&t)    pageview
analytics_debug.js:24 javaEnabled      (&je)   0
analytics_debug.js:24 language         (&ul)   en-us
analytics_debug.js:24 location         (&dl)   https://www.bu.com/thank-you
analytics_debug.js:24 screenColors     (&sd)   24-bit
analytics_debug.js:24 screenResolution (&sr)   1920x1080
analytics_debug.js:24 title            (&dt)   Thank You | Bu
analytics_debug.js:24 trackingId       (&tid)  UA-100134152-1
analytics_debug.js:24 viewportSize     (&vp)   1903x215
iframe.e378e2e8.chunk.js:1 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. 
dataLayer
1.  ecommerce:
1.  purchase:
1.  actionField: {id: 35308, affiliation: null, revenue: 78, tax: 3.9}
2.  products: Array(1)
1.  0: {name: "Buziness Vulnerability Scanning Assessment (ecomtesting.com)", id: 1506425543, brand: "Bu", category: "Bu Product", quantity: 1, …}
2.  length: 1
3.  __proto__: Array(0)
```

Its seems the Datalayes is firing, but no datas passing to Console or GA.
Please help

Comment: There are many details, which would be needed to understand your situation. Is the ecommerce data already available, when the Analytics hit is triggered? Do you initialize it with the ecommerce data, or do you push the ecommerce data in it later? Are your Analytics tag settings referring the datalayer for the ecommerce data?